# How to use functions in order?

Tags: swift

I want to use some functions.
But it works by randomly.

```
func first() {
    // using alamofire 
    case .success():
    ...
        print("1")
    }
func second() {
    // using alamofire
    ...
    case .success():
        print("2")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

@IBAcition func click(_ sender: Any) {
    first()
    second()
    }
```

If I click the button.
I expect always print : 1 2.
But It prints sometime 2 1.
How should I do?

Comment: You need to learn about asynchronous calls. One solution is to call second() from where you now have the print statement in first(). But I don’t think that is really what you want to do even if your question implies so.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using async code, move invoking of the `second` func to the `.success()` block of first func like so:

```
func first() {
    // using alamofire 
    case .success():
    ...
        print("1")
        second()
    }
```

That way you will be sure that `second` func is only called after `first` func fulfills

Answer (score 0):

```
func first(completion: @escaping(_ success:Bool) -> Void) {
    // using alamofire
    case .success():
            print("1")
         completion(true)
     case .failure():
         completion(false)
    }
func second(completion: @escaping(_ success:Bool) -> Void) {
   
    case .success():
         print("2")
         completion(true)
    case .failure():
         completion(false)
}

@IBAcition func click(_ sender: Any) {
    first { success in // first func executed
        if success { // first func success is true
            second { success in
                if success { // second func success is true
                    print("do something now")
                } else {
                    print("2nd func failed")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("1st func failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more about Asynchronous call understanding than a code issue. When making Asynchronous calls, be it an API call over the network or locally, you cannot be sure of the order it will be returned in.

For example, when calling first and second, it might be possible that the second call is returned earlier than the first. Thus creating the issue you are facing.

To solve the issue you can try the answer provided by [Zeeshan Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14699332/zeeshan-ahmed)